# Bracket of 8 Tournament

Tags: combinatorics

If I had a bracket style tournament, how many possibilities are there for a 8 team tournament. Once a team gets eliminated, they do not play a game for the 3rd place and below.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you share your own thoughts on the problem.  Have you figured out how many ways the quarterfinals can be scheduled?

Answer (score 1):

Let me just take the nice ASCII-Art @Kaligule provided:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+-O-+   +-O-+   +-O-+   +-O-+
  |       |       |       |
  +---O---+       +---O---+
      |               |
      +-------O-------+
              |
           Winner!
```

We'll start by establishing a numbered order of the eight teams as seen in the graphic. For this, there are $8!$ possibilities. We don't really care for whether a team is "on the left side" or "on the right side" of a match, so we'll divide by $2!$ for every match. So for the initial setup of the entry matches, that gives us
$$
n =  \frac{8!}{2!2!2!2!}
$$
possibilities.

Now we determine the winner of each match. Clearly, it's either the left or the right side that wins, so that gives us $2$ possibilities each. So for the (ordered) outcomes of the entry matches, we have in total
$$
n = 2^4 \cdot \frac{8!}{2!2!2!2!} = 8!
$$
possibilities.

Again, we don't really care what side each team is on for the second-level matches. So we divide by $2!$ for each. At the same time, there'll be two possible outcomes for each match again. It just so happens that we end up multiplying by $\frac{2^2}{2!2!}$ possibilities, which of course is one. So the number of (ordered) outcomes of the second level matches is
$$
n = 8!  \cdot 1 = 8!
$$

Finally, we go for the final match. Divide by $2!$, multiply by $2$.. again it comes out to one. So, if I'm not entirely mistaken, our final amount of possibilities for the matches should be:
$$
n = 8!
$$

Answer (score 1):

We can uniquely encode the outcome in the tournament in an $8$-character string as follows. The code "abcdefgh" means

- a was the winner
- b came second
- c lost to a in the semifinals
- d lost to b in the semifinals
- e lost to a in the first round
- f lost to b in the first round
- g lost to c in the first round
- f lost to d in the first round

Since there are $8!$ such strings, there are $8!$ possible outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

You are not really specific about what you want to count, but lets assume the starting positions are fix already.

There will be $7$ games (just count the `O`s in the diagram below) and each game can have $2$ outcomes (left wins or right wins). The outcomes of the single games are all that matters for the tournament, so we only have to look at them.

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+-O-+   +-O-+   +-O-+   +-O-+
  |       |       |       |
  +---O---+       +---O---+
      |               |
      +-------O-------+
              |
           Winner!
```

Since there are 2 possibilities for every game you get $2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2$ possibilities how the tournament might go.

Comment: You also have to determine who plays in each match in the quarterfinals and which quarterfinal winners will play each other in the semifinal.

Comment: I knew I shouldn't answer sports questions.